# K-Means Clustering having error of "Too many indexers" when multiple columns are given

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

The code below is of K-Means Clustering copied from [www.analyticsvidhya.com](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/08/comprehensive-guide-k-means-clustering/#h2_10)

```
K=3

# Select random observation as centroids
Centroids = (X.sample(n=K))
plt.scatter(X["DATE_ID"],X.iloc[:,-1],c='black')
plt.scatter(Centroids["DATE_ID"],Centroids.iloc[:,-1],c='red')
plt.xlabel('Number of Days')
plt.ylabel('POI1 Sales')
plt.show()
```

Output of above code

[image]

```
diff = 1
j=0

while(diff!=0):
    XD=X
    i=1
    for index1,row_c in Centroids.iterrows():
        ED=[]
        for index2,row_d in XD.iterrows():
            d1=(row_c["DATE_ID"]-row_d["DATE_ID"])**2
            d2=(row_c.iloc[:,-1]-row_d.iloc[:,-1])**2
            d=np.sqrt(d1+d2)
            ED.append(d)
        X[i]=ED
        i=i+1

C=[]
for index,row in X.iterrows():
    min_dist=row[1]
    pos=1
    for i in range(K):
        if row[i+1] < min_dist:
            min_dist = row[i+1]
            pos=i+1
    C.append(pos)
X["Cluster"]=C
Centroids_new = X.groupby(["Cluster"]).mean()[[X.iloc[:,-1],"DATE_ID"]]
if j == 0:
    diff=1
    j=j+1
else:
    diff = (Centroids_new[:,-1] - Centroids[:,-1]).sum() + (Centroids_new['DATE_ID'] - Centroids['DATE_ID']).sum()
    print(diff.sum())
Centroids = X.groupby(["Cluster"]).mean()[[X.iloc[:,-1],"DATE_ID"]]
```

The error I am having:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-19f3132fec6e> in <module>()
      9         for index2,row_d in XD.iterrows():
     10             d1=(row_c["DATE_ID"]-row_d["DATE_ID"])**2
---> 11             d2=(row_c.iloc[:,-1]-row_d.iloc[:,-1])**2
     12             d=np.sqrt(d1+d2)
     13             ED.append(d)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_key_length(self, key)
    790     def _validate_key_length(self, key: Sequence[Any]) -> None:
    791         if len(key) > self.ndim:
--> 792             raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
    793 
    794     def _getitem_tuple_same_dim(self, tup: tuple):

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

**The problem**

How can I pass multiple columns in it? the 1st column I have is DATE_ID (it's in float format) and the other columns are sales of different stores (also in float format)

I'm trying to implement [this code](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/08/comprehensive-guide-k-means-clustering/#h2_10) but the code mentioned in the link before is implemented on only 2 columns, whereas I have to implement it on multiple columns while keeping the DATE_ID column fixed.

Comment: use PCA to reduce to 2 dimensions. Or, instead of using this code, use [scikit learn's](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) implementation of kmeans.

Comment: @chitown88 Thankyou so much for the response and can you please provide any helpful code link for the sklearn's Kmeans?

Comment: sure. Can you provide a sample of your dataset that you are trying to cluster on? and also, how many clusters (K value)

Comment: @chitown88 Here is the data sample [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H4NtOJqPMnsx11ZIfBXEhu-zB14XDjq3/view?usp=sharing) 
As it is a time-series data so I need to keep the date column fixed and then pass all the columns from 1-38(POIs)
The date column contains dates of a long duration and then pois columns contains sales data

Answer (score 0):

Here's scikit learns' k-means:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('stack_overflow.csv')
X = df.iloc[:,1:]


plt.scatter(
   X['DATE_ID'], X.iloc[:, -1],
   c='white', marker='o',
   edgecolor='black', s=50
)
plt.show()


k = 3

km = KMeans(
    n_clusters=k, init='random',
    n_init=10, max_iter=300, 
    tol=1e-04, random_state=0
)
y_km = km.fit_predict(X)
X['label'] = y_km
```

Output:

[image]

Now use the labels to graph the clusters:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# plot the 3 clusters
plt.scatter(
    X[X['label'] == 0]['DATE_ID'], X[X['label'] == 0].iloc[:,-2],
    s=50, c='lightgreen',
    marker='s', edgecolor='black',
    label='cluster 1'
)

plt.scatter(
    X[X['label'] == 1]['DATE_ID'], X[X['label'] == 1].iloc[:,-2],
    s=50, c='orange',
    marker='o', edgecolor='black',
    label='cluster 2'
)

plt.scatter(
    X[X['label'] == 2]['DATE_ID'], X[X['label'] == 2].iloc[:,-2],
    s=50, c='lightblue',
    marker='v', edgecolor='black',
    label='cluster 3'
)

# plot the centroids
plt.scatter(
    km.cluster_centers_[:, 0], km.cluster_centers_[:, 1],
    s=250, marker='*',
    c='red', edgecolor='black',
    label='centroids'
)
plt.legend(scatterpoints=1)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]